# How to output the result of a chain of commands for a given input with bash

Tags: bash

In reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash/41236640#41236640) I still struggle the following single-liner to work

```
kubectl get ns | while read -r line; do  echo `$line | grep Term | cut -d' ' -f1`; done
```

I would expect to print out the result of `$line | grep Term | cut -d' ' -f1` however it prints out an empty line (`echo`) and then executes the result of `$line | grep Term | cut -d' ' -f1`

```
bash: NAME: command not found

bash: cert-manager: command not found

bash: configmap-4262: command not found

bash: configmap-4430: command not found
```

Same results with a slightly different approach:

```
kubectl get ns | while read -r line; do ns=`$line | grep Term | cut -d' ' -f1`; echo $ns; done
```

What I actually want to achieve is to use the result of `$line | grep Term | cut -d'` as an input of a shell script e.g.

```
do ns=`$line | grep Term | cut -d' ' -f1`; ./delete-kube-ns.sh $ns;
```

or

```
$line | grep Term | cut -d' ' -f1` | xargs ./delete-kube-ns.sh
```

Comment: You're trying to execute the contents of `$line` as a shell command.

Comment: To expand on the previous comment, if `$line` is `poo`, then the command `$line | grep` tries to execute `poo` and pipe its output to `grep`. You apparently want `echo "$line" | grep` etc; pay attention to the quotes around the variable, too. Code which doesn't do what you want is often a poor way to explain what you do want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your suggestion I actually could achieve what I intended to do

```
kubectl get ns | awk '/Term/ { print $1 }' | while IFS= read -r line; do
   ~/bin/kill-kube-ns.sh $line
done
Killed namespace: configmap-4500
Killed namespace: configmap-5062
Killed namespace: configmap-5526
Killed namespace: configmap-5817
Killed namespace: configmap-6143
```

Answer (score 3):

Ger rid of the backticks. It's trying to execute the output of `kubectl` as a shell command. You want to echo `$line`, not the result of executing it as a command.

```
kubectl get ns | while read -r line; do  
    echo "$line" | grep Term | cut -d' ' -f1
done
```

There doesn't really seem to be a need to use `while read` at all, just pipe `kubectl` to `grep`

```
kubectl get ns | grep Term | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Comment: Yeah maybe my question was not properly enough, the `echo` was just an example for me on the way to get an understanding. What I want in the end is to something like this ```do ns=`$line | grep Term | cut -d' ' -f1`; ./delete-kube-ns.sh $ns;```

Answer (score 1):

A `parameter expansion` might be what you want/need, instead of embedding `grep` and `cut` inside a `while read` loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

kubectl get ns | while IFS= read -r line; do  
  [[ $line == Term ]] && ns=${line% *}
  echo "$ns"
done
```

Depending on the pattern match, you might need `*Term*`

Comment: `kubectl get ns | awk '/Term/{print $1}'`

Answer (score 1):

Any combo of `grep` and `cut` (and `head`, `tall`, etc, as well as `sed`) suggests a reimplementation in Awk. Saving one external process is a minor optimization, but this often invites additional simple improvements. For example, should the regex cover the whole line, or is it only really supposed to look for matches in the first field? That's not impossible with `grep`, either, of course, but quite easy in Awk.

```sh
kubectl get ns |
awk '/Term/ { print $1 }'
```

If you only wanted to look for `Term` in the first field, that's `'$1 ~ /Term/ { ...`

You can extend this with a pipe to

```
... | xargs ./delete-kube-ns.sh
```

if that's your end goal.